# How to spread divs around without overlapping each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building an event scheduler and I've gotten into a point that I can't figure out a way to spread events around without overlapping each other. (It might have events at the same time and without limits. Whenever is possible, use 100% of the available `width`)

Here it is a picture of this scenario.
[image]

**Some considerations:**

- The events is wrapped inside a div with `position: relative` and all the events has `position:absolute`.
- Using javascript, I have to figure out what needs to be the value of `top` `left` `width` and `height` of each "div event" on the fly.
- Events are an array of objects like the code below:

  {
      startAt: "12:00:30",
      endsAt: "13:00:00",
      description: "evt1",
      id: '00001'
  }
- I'm using Vue.js to develop this project. But this is not an issue if you don't know Vue. I've build a small project using jsbin so you can just play around with a javascript function.

Live Code: https://jsbin.com/bipesoy/

**Where I'm having problem?**

I can't find a algorithm to calculate the `top` `left` `width` and `height` on the fly based on an array of events.

**Some considerations about the jsbin code:**

- All the code to find the 4 properties above is inside the function `parsedEvents`
- Inside `parsedEvents` you can access the array of events using: `this.events`
- The job of `parsedEvents` is loop through the array of events and add the style propertie to each one and then return a new array of events with the style object.
- Each 30 minutes has a height of 40px;

Any ideas how to accomplish it or a better solution?

Comment: From the top of my head, I'd not loop through events but through 30min increments, counting number of events that fall in each 30-minutes span. Then loop thruogh items and 1) find out which 30min-increments are overlapped with this item, 2) find max count from all those overlapped 30min-increments and that is your width (for count 3 it's 33%, for 2 its 50%, etc.). I guess hight is not a problem as it is just a multiplication of item duration/0.5h x 40 px

Comment: Sounds promising @MirkoVukušić . I'll try it out and let you know later :)

Comment: @MirkoVukušić actually I think there is a problem with the width. Look at evt2 and evt7 in the pic. What would be their width?

Comment: Ups,  yes.  Actually evt2 and every other event but evt7 would be ok,  but evt7 would be 50% which would not overlap bit would not look nice.  This is really interesting task,  I love those :)  But im not near PC for the next 4 hours. Ill definetly look into it then unless you get the answer

Comment: It's still work in progress but here is a snapshot: http://jsbin.com/jaloyiw/42/edit?js,console,output
There are more issues than using maximum space. I added one more event to test, evt8, between 4:30 and 6:00. There are 2 options to place this one: 1) to the right below evt5 and evt6 but double in size and 2) below evt3 and between evt2 and evt4.
Same problem is visible if you delete evts 5-8 and add one from 5:00 to 6:00.  It will overlap with evt4. Same improvement on logic of horizontal positioning will fix all this, but that tomorrow :)

Comment: @MirkoVukušić I think without repositioning the events is impossible to accomplish a calendar nice view. Has been a great challenge to find a solution to this hehehe. What I am trying to implement now is a little different. 1) Find the time span with more events 2) Order them by startAt(which will make than print like a diagonal and make available full width whenever is possible to other events inside this "square") 3)print 4)loop again to find the second row with more but now I will have to check from left to right if it has available space.... a nightmare hehehe

Comment: repositioning is not an issue :) It's really a challenge. But I think I'm near solution. Too bad I don't have as much time I would like to spend. I refactored a bit and managed to do all except expanding. That will have to wait for tonight. Current snapshot of my (refactored) unfinished work is here: http://jsbin.com/humiyi/47/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some time playing with this challenge I think it's time to give up from the idea. It is possible to program many possible scenarios of arranging events, but when you dig deep you realize it's very difficult to even write what exactly you want to be done and even if you manage, some of your decisions just don't look good on the screen. This is only with expanding events in width. Positioning and even re-positioning them to fill gaps is solved and not too difficult.

Snippet is here (or JSBin if you prefer: http://jsbin.com/humiyi/99/edit?html,js,console,output).

Green events are detected as "expandable". Grey o nes cannot expand. To clarify problems with logic of expanding, some examples:

- evt 1 and evt3? it can be like this or evt3 goes right and they both expand
- evt7 and evt12? Many ways to expand this... how to define a rule?
- imagine evt7 and evt11 ar merged into one big event. How to expand evt10, evt7/11 and evt 12?
  ... now try to write rules to consistently answer on above 3 (and many many more possible scenarios not in this example)

My conclusion is that writing rules and developing this is not worth the effort. UI usability will not get much. They will even loose in some scenarios, i.e. some events would be visually bigger just because they have space and not because they're more important.

I'd suggest layout similar or exactly the same as the one in example. Events just don't expand. I don't know how much daily events you expect, what's real life scenario, but only upgrade I'd potentially do is to split vertically calendar in separated regions - point in time which is not overlapping with any event, like line between evt7 and evt11 in example. Then run this same script per region independently. That will recalculate vertical slots per region so region with evt10 i evt11 will have only 2 vertical slots filling space 50% each. This maybe be worth it if your calendar has few crowded hours and only a few events later/before. This would fix an issue of too narrow events later in the day without spending much time. But if events are all over the day and overlapping alot I don't think it's worth it.

```js
let events = [
  { startAt: "00:00", endsAt: "01:00", description: "evt1", id: '00001' },
  { startAt: "01:30", endsAt: "08:00", description: "evt2", id: '00002' },
  { startAt: "01:30", endsAt: "04:00", description: "evt3", id: '00003' },
  { startAt: "00:30", endsAt: "02:30", description: "evt3", id: '00013' },
  { startAt: "00:00", endsAt: "01:00", description: "evt3", id: '00014' },
  { startAt: "03:00", endsAt: "06:00", description: "evt4", id: '00004' },
  { startAt: "01:30", endsAt: "04:30", description: "evt5", id: '00005' },
  { startAt: "01:30", endsAt: "07:00", description: "evt6", id: '00006' },
  { startAt: "06:30", endsAt: "09:00", description: "evt7", id: '00007' },
  { startAt: "04:30", endsAt: "06:00", description: "evt8", id: '00008' },
  { startAt: "05:00", endsAt: "06:00", description: "evt9", id: '00009' },
  { startAt: "09:00", endsAt: "10:00", description: "evt10", id: '00010' },
  { startAt: "09:00", endsAt: "10:30", description: "evt11", id: '00011' },
  { startAt: "07:00", endsAt: "08:00", description: "evt12", id: '00012' }
]

console.time()

// will store counts of events in each 30-min chunk
// each element represents 30 min chunk starting from midnight
// ... so indexOf * 30 minutes = start time
// it will also store references to events for each chunk
// each element format will be: { count: <int>, eventIds: <array_of_ids> }
let counter = []

// helper to convert time to counter index
time2index = (time) => {
  let splitTime = time.split(":")
  return parseInt(splitTime[0]) * 2 + parseInt(splitTime[1])/30
}

// loop through events and fill up counter with data
events.map(event => {
  for (let i = time2index(event.startAt); i < time2index(event.endsAt); i++) {
    if (counter[i] && counter[i].count) {
      counter[i].count++
      counter[i].eventIds.push(event.id)
    } else {
      counter[i] = { count: 1, eventIds: [event.id] }
    }
  }
})

//find chunk with most items. This will become number of slots (vertical spaces) for our calendar grid
let calSlots = Math.max( ...counter.filter(c=>c).map(c=>c.count) ) // filtering out undefined elements
console.log("number of calendar slots: " + calSlots)

// loop through events and add some more props to each:
// - overlaps: all overlapped events (by ref)
// - maxOverlapsInChunk: number of overlapped events in the most crowded chunk
//   (1/this is maximum number of slots event can occupy)
// - pos: position of event from left (in which slot it starts)
// - expandable: if maxOverlapsInChunk = calSlot, this event is not expandable for sure
events.map(event => {
  let overlappedEvents = events.filter(comp => {
    return !(comp.endsAt <= event.startAt || comp.startAt >= event.endsAt || comp.id === event.id)
  })
  event.overlaps = overlappedEvents //stores overlapped events by reference!
  event.maxOverlapsInChunk = Math.max( ...counter.filter(c=>c).map(c=>c.eventIds.indexOf(event.id) > -1 ? c.count : 0))
  event.expandable = event.maxOverlapsInChunk !== calSlots
  event.pos = Math.max( ...counter.filter(c=>c).map( c => {
    let p = c.eventIds.indexOf(event.id)
    return p > -1 ? p+1 : 1
  }))
})

// loop to move events leftmost possible and fill gaps if any
// some expandable events will stop being expandable if they fit gap perfectly - we will recheck those later
events.map(event => {
  if (event.pos > 1) {
    //find positions of overlapped events on the left side
    let vertSlotsTakenLeft = event.overlaps.reduce((result, cur) => {
      if (result.indexOf(cur.pos) < 0 && cur.pos < event.pos) result.push(cur.pos)
      return result
    }, [])
    
    // check if empty space on the left
    for (i = 1; i < event.pos; i++) {
      if (vertSlotsTakenLeft.indexOf(i) < 0) {
        event.pos = i
        console.log("moving " + event.description + " left to pos " + i)
        break
      }
    }
  }
})

// fix moved events if they became non-expandable because of moving
events.filter(event=>event.expandable).map(event => {
  let leftFixed = event.overlaps.filter(comp => {
    return event.pos - 1 === comp.pos && comp.maxOverlapsInChunk === calSlots
  })
  let rightFixed = event.overlaps.filter(comp => {
    return event.pos + 1 === comp.pos && comp.maxOverlapsInChunk === calSlots
  })
  event.expandable = (!leftFixed.length || !rightFixed.length)
})

//settings for calendar (positioning events)
let calendar = {width: 300, chunkHeight: 30}

// one more loop through events to calculate top, left, width and height
events.map(event => {
  event.top = time2index(event.startAt) * calendar.chunkHeight
  event.height = time2index(event.endsAt) * calendar.chunkHeight - event.top
  //event.width = 1/event.maxOverlapsInChunk * calendar.width
  event.width = calendar.width/calSlots // TODO: temporary width is 1 slot 
  event.left = (event.pos - 1) * calendar.width/calSlots 
})

console.timeEnd()

// TEST drawing divs
events.map(event => {
  $("body").append(`<div style="position: absolute;
    top: ${event.top}px;
    left: ${event.left}px;
    width: ${event.width}px;
    height: ${event.height}px;
    background-color: ${event.expandable ? "green" : "grey"};
    border: solid black 1px;
    ">${event.description}</div>`)
})

//console.log(events)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uau @MirkoVukušić you are right. Normally, it won't be too many overlapping events. I'll finish my project as you suggested. Thank you very much for the great answer!! :)

Answer (score 0):

was thinking more about this. I covered width, height, and top. But you might have issues with calculating `left`. So a little change... goal to create counters for each 30-min increment still remains, but instead of looping through increments and filtering items, do it vice versa. Loop through items and fill that counter object from there. It will also be faster. While on that loop, don't just store counter to counter object, but also push itemID to another property of the same object (and the same increment). So, each increment can be represented like {span: "17:00", counter: 2, items: [135, 148]}. This `items` array will later help you to determine `left` position of each item and avoid horizontal overlapping. Because *maximal* poistion of the item in `items` array across all increments of the item = position of the item on the calendar from left. Multiply it with width (-1) and you have `left`.